# Минимальное время выполнения цикла на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть цикл

```
i = 0
while i <= 25:
    do_something()
    i += 1
```

Нужно сделать так, чтобы 1 проход по циклу выполнялся ровно 1 секунду

Comment: Что такое в вашем понимании "минимально выполнялся за 1 секунду"?

Comment: @Alexander чтобы 1 проход по циклу совершался ровно за одну секунду

Comment: time.sleep(1) на каждой итерации - не?

Comment: Может вы расскажете, для чего это нужно? А то может вы делаете какое-то костыльное решение проблемы, которую можно решить, не заставляя поток насильно спать

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов простите, я немного ошибся. 1 проход по циклу должен выполняться ровно 1 секунду

Comment: После `i += 1`, на следующей строке добавьте `time.sleep(1)`

Comment: Не будет у вас "ровно" никак, потому что с вероятностью стремящейся к единице у вас не ОС реального времени. Плюс Питон, который непонятно какие плавающие задержки внесет

Comment: @Alexander есть задача: камера должна совершать 25 кадров в секунду и сохранять их, после чего они должны обновляться каждую секунду

Comment: а камера фиически успевает сделать 25 кадров в режиме фотографии? Это всё же не видео.

Comment: @pavel может это камера в игре)

Comment: @ІлляБогомол замеряйте, сколько времени уходит на выполнение `do_something()` и каждую итерацию останавливайте поток на `1/25 - doSomethingDeltaTime` секунд

Comment: @pavel она их вырезает во время видеопотока. С помощь библиотеки OpenCV

Answer (score 0):

(сорри, не могу пока ещё оставлять комментарии).

> есть задача: камера должна совершать 25 кадров в секунду и сохранять их, после чего они должны обновляться каждую секунду

Если я правильно понял твою задачу, то в opencv ты можешь итерироваться по фреймам.

Пример есть тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954889/how-to-process-images-of-a-video-frame-by-frame-in-video-streaming-using-opencv

Answer (score 0):

импортируйте модуль time и перед 4 строкой напишите sleep(1)

Comment: Не учитывается время на выполнение do_something.